# Getting errors when using forward declarations of a class in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, forward-declaration

I'm having an issue trying to use the forward declaration of one of my classes in Xcode.

Here's my basic architecture:

MyClassA.h:

```
class MyClassA{
  ... list of members and method prototypes ...
};
```

MyClassA.cpp:

```
#include "MyClassA.h"

--- list of methods for MyClassA ...
```

MyClassB.h:

```
class MyClassA; // forward declaration

class MyClassB{
  ... list of members and methods ...
  MyClassA* ptrToA;
};
```

MyClassB.cpp:

```
#include "MyClassB.h"

... list of methods for MyClassB ...
```

This works on my windows machine in Visual Studio no problem, do it all the time.  However, on the Mac in Xcode it's giving me the error:

```
Forward declaration of 'struct MyClassA'
```

Any ideas?  The error message doesn't seem to make much sense since I declared class plain as day and it's coming back with an error about a struct.  Are forward declarations not supported in Xcode (pretty simple error message seems to indicate this is the issue, other than the struct/class confusion)?  My project is compiled as C++, not C.  Is there another project setting I'm missing that could be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you try to trim it down to an example that you can quote in full.  Then people won't have to wonder, for instance, whether you really left off the semicolon at the end of the declaration of `MyClassA`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `#include "MyClassA.h"`
 in MyClassB.cpp, unless you don't intend to dereference `ptrToA`, or otherwise need to know anything about the underlying type.

Comment: My fault.  Thanks anyway.  I simply misunderstood how forward declarations work.  I was trying to use the forward declaration as a substitute for including MyClassA.h in MyClassB.h, hoping after all is linked it would then get what it needed (Objective-C DOES work this way from what I found).

If I include MyClassA.h, then there's no reason for me to even write a forward declaration... the full declaration is already there and available from the include.

Comment: @TheoJohn you didn't show us all the relevant code. It is a fairly common technique you're describing, very useful to improve compile time.

Comment: I replaced the actual class names and other unrelated members and methods (bunch of floats, chars, and constructors), but everything I put in my example code above is 100% of the **relevant** code as it was architected.

Comment: Point out what code you think is missing and I can try and include it to help.

Answer (score 0):

What line of code is actually causing the error? My expectation is that you have forgotten to include MyClassA.h in MyClassB.cpp, and the error is actually happening when you try to `new` the object.

Classes are structs. They just mark their members private by default, while structs mark them public.

Comment: The error is right on the actual forward declaration itself. I haven't written any code to "new" the object yet.

Comment: It looks like I just simply misunderstood how forward declarations work.  I've used them a lot before, but not in the fasion I remembered (just looked back to some older code).  Everywhere I used them was simply because the ClassA and ClassB existed together in the same header, and also referenced each other, the forward declaration was needed.

So in the current case of what I'm trying to do I do need to include ClassA.h in ClassB.h... however, in doing so makes using a forward declaration completely pointless because the full declaration of the class would already exist.

Comment: No, I don't think you misunderstood at all. If all you need is a pointer to ClassA, the forward declaration is all you need. But as soon as you start to use it, like allocating an object or calling member functions, you need the full declaration. If that is what you do in ClassB.cpp, you need to include ClassA.h there.

Comment: Okay, hmmm... still ponders the question then why Xcode throws an error and won't even let me set the forward declaration.  I just typed the same thing into Visual Studio as a test, and it did compile just fine as I expected.  Thanks.